# Структура "Студент", вывод фамилий и номеров групп студентов имеющих положительные оценки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ооп, visual-c++

Изучаю самостоятельно С++. Добрался до ООП.
Решаю задачи. А именно:
"Создайте структуру с именем student, содержащую поля: фамилия и инициалы, номер группы, успеваемость (массив из пяти элементов). Создать массив из десяти элементов такого типа, упорядочить записи по возрастанию среднего балла. Добавить возможность вывода фамилий и номеров групп студентов, имеющих оценки, равные только 4 или 5."

Немного модифицировал задание, создав класс. И добавив динамическое выделение памяти, чтобы потренироваться. Буду благодарен за проверку. А вообще хочу получить рекомендации "Как сделать лучше", "Что требуется поменять", "Что и почему лучше использовать", "Как делать нельзя".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/*
    1. Создайте структуру с именем student, содержащую поля: фамилия и инициалы, номер группы, успеваемость (массив из пяти элементов).
    Создать массив из десяти элементов такого типа, упорядочить записи по возрастанию среднего балла.
    Добавить возможность вывода фамилий и номеров групп студентов, имеющих оценки, равные только 4 или 5.
*/

class Student
{
public:
    Student()
    {
        /* string str;
        cout << "Фамилия студента: ";   cin >> str;
        this->sirname = str;
        cout << "Инициалы: ";   cin >> str;
        this->inicial = str;*/

        sirname = "";
        inicial = "";
        number = 0;

        /*while (true)
        {
            int num;
            cout << "Номер группы: ";   cin >> num;
            if (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
                cout << "Неверный номер группы! Введите корректно!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
                this->number = num;
                break;
            }
        }*/

        /* while (true)
        {
            int num;
            _flushall();
            rewind(stdin);
            printf_s("Номер группы: "); scanf_s("%d", &num);
            if (getchar() != '\n'&& getchar() != EOF || num < 1000 || num >9999)
            {
                printf_s("Неверный номер группы! Введите корректно!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                this->number = num;
                break;
            }
        }*/
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int inputData = rand() % 4 + 2;
            this->uspev[i] = inputData;
        }

    }

    Student(string sirname, string inicial, int number) :Student()
    {
        this->sirname = sirname;
        this->inicial = inicial;
        this->number = number;
    }

    Student(string sirname, string inicial, int number, int *uspev) :Student(sirname, inicial, number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            this->uspev[i] = uspev[i];
        }
    }

    ~Student()
    {
        //cout << "\nВызван деструктор " << this << endl;
        if (uspev != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] uspev;
        }
        //cout << "Данные удалены" << endl;
    }

    /* Конструктор копирования */
    Student(const Student &copyObject)
    {
        this->sirname = copyObject.sirname;
        this->inicial = copyObject.inicial;
        this->number = copyObject.number;
        this->uspev = new int[copyObject.n];
        for (int i = 0; i < copyObject.n; i++)
        {
            this->uspev[i] = copyObject.uspev[i];
        }
    }

    void PrintStud()
    {
        cout << "Фамилия студента: " + sirname << endl;
        cout << "Инициалы студента: " + inicial << endl;
        cout << "Номер группы: ПАО_" << number << endl;
        cout << "Оценки студента: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < this->n; i++)
        {
            cout << this->uspev[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\nСредний балл студента: " << SrBal() << endl;
    }

    void SetStud(string sirname, string inicial, int number)
    {
        this->sirname = sirname;
        this->inicial = inicial;
        this->number = number;
    }

    double SrBal()
    {
        double srBal = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            srBal += uspev[i];
        }
        return srBal / n;
    }

    /* Перегрузка оператора присваивания */
    Student& operator = (const Student & other)
    {
        if (this->uspev != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] this->uspev;
        }
        this->sirname = other.sirname;
        this->inicial = other.inicial;
        this->number = other.number;
        this->uspev = new int[other.n];
        for (int i = 0; i < other.n; i++)
        {
            this->uspev[i] = other.uspev[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    /* Перегрузки операторов сравнения */
    bool operator ==(const Student &other)
    {
        return this->sirname == other.sirname&&this->inicial == other.inicial&&this->number == other.number&&this->uspev == other.uspev;
    }
    bool operator !=(const Student &other)
    {
        return !(this->sirname == other.sirname&&this->inicial == other.inicial&&this->number == other.number&&this->uspev == other.uspev);
    }
    bool operator >(const Student &other)
    {
        return this->sirname > other.sirname&&this->inicial > other.inicial&&this->number > other.number&&this->uspev > other.uspev;
    }
    bool operator >=(const Student &other)
    {
        return this->sirname >= other.sirname&&this->inicial >= other.inicial&&this->number >= other.number&&this->uspev >= other.uspev;
    }
    bool operator <(const Student &other)
    {
        return this->sirname < other.sirname&&this->inicial < other.inicial&&this->number < other.number&&this->uspev < other.uspev;
    }
    bool operator <=(const Student &other)
    {
        return this->sirname <= other.sirname&&this->inicial <= other.inicial&&this->number <= other.number&&this->uspev <= other.uspev;
    }

    int & operator [](int index)
    {
        return uspev[index];
    }

    bool CheckFourOrFive()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (uspev[i] < 4)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

private:
    const int n = 5;

    string sirname;
    string inicial;
    int number;
    int *uspev = new int[n];
    
};

void SortSrBal(Student *st, const int size)
{
    Student temp;
    // Сортировка массива пузырьком
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (st[j].SrBal() > st[j + 1].SrBal())
            {
                temp = st[j];
                st[j] = st[j + 1];
                st[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void OutputFourOrFive(Student *st, const int size)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (st[i].CheckFourOrFive())
        {
            st[i].PrintStud();
            cout << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0)
    {
        cout << "Нет студентов с оценками 4 и 5 !!!" << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int N = 5;

    Student *STUD = new Student[N];

    system("cls");

    STUD[0].SetStud("Зажорин", "С.А.", 1398);
    STUD[1].SetStud("Иванов", "И.И.", 4417);
    STUD[2].SetStud("Петров", "В.П.", 2341);
    STUD[3].SetStud("Сидоров", "И.З.", 6715);
    STUD[4].SetStud("Кочкин", "Л.П.", 4567);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        STUD[i].PrintStud();
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "================================================================\n";
    cout << "================================================================\n\n";

    cout << "Сортировка хлопчиков по возрастанию(средний балл)_:\n\n";

    SortSrBal(STUD, N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        STUD[i].PrintStud();
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "================================================================\n";
    cout << "================================================================\n\n";

    cout << "Вывод студентов \"только\" с оценками 4 и 5_:\n\n";

    OutputFourOrFive(STUD, N);


    delete[] STUD;
    return 0;
}
```

С уважением.

***Дополнено***.
**Отредактировал. Прошу проверить и дать советы)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void StartInputConsole();
void EndInputConsole();

/*
    1. Создайте структуру с именем student, содержащую поля: фамилия и инициалы, номер группы, успеваемость (массив из пяти элементов).
    Создать массив из десяти элементов такого типа, упорядочить записи по возрастанию среднего балла.
    Добавить возможность вывода фамилий и номеров групп студентов, имеющих оценки, равные только 4 или 5.
*/

class Student
{
public:
    Student()
    {       
        sirname = "";
        inicial = "";
        number = 0;

        cout << "Введите фамилию студента: ";
        StartInputConsole();
        getline(cin, sirname);
        EndInputConsole();

        cout << "Введите инициалы студента: ";
        StartInputConsole();
        getline(cin, inicial);
        EndInputConsole();

        cout << "Введите номер группы(4 цифры): ";
        cin >> number;
        cin.ignore(32767, '\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int inputData = rand() % 4 + 2;
            this->uspev.at(i) = inputData;
        }
    }

    Student(string sirname, string inicial, int number) /* :Student()*/
    {
        this->sirname = sirname;
        this->inicial = inicial;
        this->number = number;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int inputData = rand() % 4 + 2;
            this->uspev.at(i) = inputData;
        }
    }

    Student(string sirname, string inicial, int number, array<int, 5> &uspev) :Student(sirname, inicial, number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            this->uspev.at(i) = uspev.at(i);
        }
    }

    ~Student()
    {       
    }

    /* Конструктор копирования */
    Student(const Student &copyObject)
    {
        this->sirname = copyObject.sirname;
        this->inicial = copyObject.inicial;
        this->number = copyObject.number;
        this->uspev = copyObject.uspev;
        for (int i = 0; i < copyObject.n; i++)
        {
            this->uspev.at(i) = copyObject.uspev.at(i);
        }
    }

    void PrintStud()
    {
        cout << "Фамилия студента: " + sirname << endl;
        cout << "Инициалы студента: " + inicial << endl;
        cout << "Номер группы: ПАО_" << number << endl;
        cout << "Оценки студента: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << this->uspev.at(i) << " ";
        }
        cout << "\nСредний балл студента: " << SrBal() << endl;
    }

    void SetStud(string sirname, string inicial, int number)
    {
        this->sirname = sirname;
        this->inicial = inicial;
        this->number = number;
    }

    double SrBal()
    {
        double srBal = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            srBal += uspev.at(i);
        }
        return srBal / n;
    }

    /* Перегрузка оператора присваивания */
    Student& operator = (const Student & other)
    {
        
        this->sirname = other.sirname;
        this->inicial = other.inicial;
        this->number = other.number;
        this->uspev = other.uspev;
        for (int i = 0; i < other.n; i++)
        {
            this->uspev.at(i) = other.uspev.at(i);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ///* Перегрузки операторов сравнения */
    //bool operator ==(const Student &other)
    //{
    //  return this->sirname == other.sirname&&this->inicial == other.inicial&&this->number == other.number&&this->uspev == other.uspev;
    //}
    //bool operator !=(const Student &other)
    //{
    //  return !(this->sirname == other.sirname&&this->inicial == other.inicial&&this->number == other.number&&this->uspev == other.uspev);
    //}
    //bool operator >(const Student &other)
    //{
    //  return this->sirname > other.sirname&&this->inicial > other.inicial&&this->number > other.number&&this->uspev > other.uspev;
    //}
    //bool operator >=(const Student &other)
    //{
    //  return this->sirname >= other.sirname&&this->inicial >= other.inicial&&this->number >= other.number&&this->uspev >= other.uspev;
    //}
    //bool operator <(const Student &other)
    //{
    //  return this->sirname < other.sirname&&this->inicial < other.inicial&&this->number < other.number&&this->uspev < other.uspev;
    //}
    //bool operator <=(const Student &other)
    //{
    //  return this->sirname <= other.sirname&&this->inicial <= other.inicial&&this->number <= other.number&&this->uspev <= other.uspev;
    //}

    /*int & operator [](int index)
    {
        return uspev[index];
    }*/
    
    bool CheckFourOrFive()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (uspev.at(i) < 4)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        
        return count == 0;
    }

private:
    static const int n = 5;

    string sirname;
    string inicial;
    int number;

    array<int, n> uspev;
};

void SortSrBal(vector<Student> &st)
{
    sort(st.begin(), st.end(), [](Student& a, Student& b) { return a.SrBal() < b.SrBal(); });
}


void OutputFourOrFive(vector<Student> &st)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < st.size(); i++)
    {
        if (st[i].CheckFourOrFive())
        {
            st[i].PrintStud();
            cout << endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0)
    {
        cout << "Нет студентов с оценками 4 и 5 !!!" << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int N = 5;

    
    vector<Student> STUD;

    array<int, N> arr{ 5, 4, 5, 4, 5 };

    STUD.push_back(Student("Зажорин", "С.А.", 1398));
    STUD.push_back(Student("Иванов", "И.И.", 4417));
    STUD.push_back(Student("Петров", "В.П.", 2341, arr));
    STUD.push_back(Student("Сидоров", "И.З.", 6715));
    STUD.push_back(Student("Кочкин", "Л.П.", 4567));

    STUD.push_back(Student());

    system("cls");      

    for (int i = 0; i < STUD.size(); i++)
    {
        STUD.at(i).PrintStud();
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "================================================================\n";
    cout << "================================================================\n\n";

    cout << "Сортировка хлопчиков по возрастанию(средний балл)_:\n\n";
    
    SortSrBal(STUD);

    for (int i = 0; i < STUD.size(); i++)
    {
        STUD.at(i).PrintStud();
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "================================================================\n";
    cout << "================================================================\n\n";

    cout << "Вывод студентов \"только\" с оценками 4 и 5_:\n\n";

    OutputFourOrFive(STUD);


    _getch();
    return 0;
}





// Функции:

void StartInputConsole()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
}

void EndInputConsole()
{
    SetConsoleCP(866);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(866);
}
```

Comment: а зачем редактировать? теперь все комментарии в моем вопросе потеряли смысл.

Comment: Прошу прощения, поспешил, не подумал). Вернул как было, ответом создам исправленный вариант

Comment: лучше либо дополните ответ, либо создайте новый вопрос. Что лучше - тут тонкая грань

Comment: @KoVadim проверьте пожалуйста дополненный код) Укажите что еще возможно оптимизировать. Спасибо

Comment: в многие функции лучше передавать по `const string&`, и подобно, если переменная не планируется меняться. std::array это value тип, а значит не нужно поэлементно копировать, можно просто присвоить. Но конструктор, который ещё делает ввод данных - это полный перебор. Сделайте отдельную функцию, которая будет вводить данные и возвращать готовый объект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну как минимум не нужно делать `int *uspev = new int[n];`. Если размер фиксирован - используйте просто массив/std::array, если размер может меняться - std::vector. Это очень сильно упростит код. Даже позволит отказаться от самописных конструкторов копирования.

---

```
if (count == 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

это можно в одну строку

```
return count == 0;
```

---

SortSrBal - а может в ней использовать стандартную std::sort?

---

операторы сравнения... тут явно с пробелами нужно поработать. А потом стает понятно одно - они неверны. У Вас требуется, что бы все переменные были "одного знака". А что делать с теми случаями, когда это не выполняется? то есть, у Вас может быть, что a > b и a < b будет одновременно false, и при этом a != b. Это обычно приводит к плохой сортировке.

---

вот такая конструкция не имеет смысла

```
if (uspev != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] uspev;
    }
```

delete умеет работать с nullptr самостоятельно.

---

многие куски кода можно упростить, если использовать алгоритмы стандартной библиотеки. Но, возможно, это запрещено под страхом сильных наказаний.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за советы и комментарии. Исправлю код выложу его. Я просто еще не дошел в изучении до array, vector, sort. Это насколько я понимаю библиотеки <array><vector> и <algorithm>? С операторами сравнения я тоже займусь. По поводу delete в изучении, применялась такая конструкция в примере при наследовании. Когда деструктор удалил данные, а потом вызывался еще раз delete уже к удаленным данным. Или это неверно? С уважением.

Comment: `delete data; delete data;` - такой код почти всегда ошибка. А вот `delete data; data = nullptr; delete data;` безопасно. а сам delete не зануляет указатель.

Comment: Начал переделывать. Сделал `STUD` std::vector, а `uspev` std::array. Не могу разобраться как отсортировать в std::sort по методу `double SrBal()`. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: где то так `std::sort(STUD, STUD+N, [](Student& a, Student& b) { return a.SrBal() < b.SrBal(); };` STUD можно тоже в вектор переделать и использовать push_back.

Comment: Ругается на `sort` "отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция и на `STUD+N` отсутствует оператор "+". Еще лямда - функция, я слышал про нее, но еще не изучал. Буду думать и стараться. Как закончу выложу код на проверку. Спасибо.

Comment: Вроде разобрался с `std::sort(STUD, STUD+N, [](Student& a, Student& b) { return a.SrBal() < b.SrBal(); };`, поменял немного, заработало `sort(STUD.begin(), STUD.end(), [](Student& a, Student& b) { return a.SrBal() < b.SrBal(); });`. Еще бы разобраться в этой записи))). `[](Student& a, Student& b) { return a.SrBal() < b.SrBal(); }` это условие для сортировки?

Comment: это функтор, который задает правила для сортирвки, если переопределить оператор меньше для Student, то можно обойтись и без функтора

Comment: Оператор можно переопределить, но думаю, что отдельная функция сравнения значительно лучше в данном случае.